# Stirling number and cycles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, stirling-numbers

I was introduced stirling number of first kind [s(n,k)] as number of ways one can arrange n people around k identical tables and permuting them. But coefficent of x^k in the polynomial: x(x+1)(x+2)......(x+n-1) gives me the value of s(n,k). Can this be justified by some combinatorial interpretation (with arrangement of n people in k distinct tables and permuting them ).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a triangular recurrence relation for the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind which count the number of permutations of n elements with k disjoint cycles. It's easy to obtain this recurrence relation from the product you have written out above. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation).